# How make dropdowns in php pages?

Tags: php, html

I made a form to create an account which contains several fields. Those are: name,address,phone,secret question etc. This is working fine, but I face a problem in making the edit page. How can I repopulate the secret question dropdown field?
Please guide my html code is like following:

```
<select name="securityqustion"  class="securityqustion"  >
<option value="<?php echo $row['scruity_question'];?>" selected >
<?php echo   $row['scruity_question'];?></option>
<option class="option"  value="what is your nickname">what is your nickname</option>
<option value="what is your first school">what is your first school</option>
</select>
```

In the above code the selected question is repeated.

Comment: Sidenote: nickname as a security question is not really safe: all my friends would be able to request a new password for my account just by "guessing" that...First school also, even my relatives would know that!:D Use something which is really difficult to guess, even with social engineering; or better, don't use security questions at all

Comment: this is the id which i used to handle css and other things which not required here

Comment: @DamienPirsy i give you the examples,later on i modify it according to the requirements

Comment: @user696734 he means you wrote "scruity_question" as array index..is it right? is it spelt that way?

Comment: no it does not belong to that by mistake i write that,i removed that

Comment: @user696734 `$row['scruity_question']` SCRUITY QUESTION != SECURITY QUESTION . He meant that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to build that from an array and check if the iterated value is the desired one, so you can add `selected` to it.

This code generates the list and selects the `<option>` which matches the `$row['scruity_question']`

```
<select name="securityqustion"  class="securityqustion" id="security_qustion">
<?php
  $questions = array("what is your nickname", "what is your first school", "whats your cats name");
  forand compare each ($questions as $question) {
    if ($question == $row['scruity_question']) 
      $selected = "selected"
    else 
      $selected = "";
    echo "<option value=\"{$question}\" {$selected}>{$question}</option>\n";
  }
?>
</select>
```

**NOTE**

Storing the security question as a string is a bad idea - when you change the spelling of a question it doesn't match whats stored in the database. Better put the questions into a seperate database table and use the ID of a question for references.

**SIDENODE** from Damien Pirsy (important enough to be included in an answer)

nickname as a security question is not really safe: all my friends would be able to request a new password for my account just by "guessing" that...First school also, even my relatives would know that!:D Use something which is really difficult to guess, even with social engineering; or better, don't use security questions at all – Damien Pirsy

Comment: thank you so much,i got the point,i will use database for storing all question and then retrieve for comparsion

Comment: how to vote i do not know really,please help me in this regards

Comment: there are arrow buttons beside the answer.. please read this FAQ: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)