# Generate Drop Down From MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, menu

I need to generate a drop down menu from data in a MySQL table.

From the table, it'll have to take the user id and the username.

Then it'll set the user id to option value and the username to what shows up in the drop down.

Could anyone show me some code for it? I'm having trouble making the following work:

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id, user_name FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<option value=\".$row['user_id'].\">.$row['user_name'].</option>\n ";
  echo "<option value=\"12275\">".$row['user_name']."</option>\n ";
}
```

Comment: Good luck! Let us know if you're having any troubles.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This site isn't for getting free code, it's for helping you with your code.

Comment: What have you tried... What are you having problems with?   What is your question?

Comment: @OOProg, Better Edit and ask a vaild and understandable question and before that do some HW. There are big guys here who are here to both help you and also pounce on you for every bad question ;-)

Comment: read [How to make dropdowns in PHP pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298519/how-make-dropdowns-in-php-pages/9298854#9298854)

Comment: @Kaii - I wish every problem had a perfectly titled article. +1

Comment: The only thing i can detect is that you forgot the `<select></select>` tag that contain your option values. Plus your first echo is a mess, you forgot to close and open string. It is great that you escaped the " char for the html output, but you miss the one to close and open string in php.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues with your output. First, it's not clear from your example if you have the actual `select` element parent, and I'm not sure if browsers will display `options` without a parent select.  Second, you are not escaping your array variables. So this might fix it:

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id, user_name FROM users"; $result=mysql_query($sql);

echo '<select name="users">';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<option value="'. $row['user_id'] . '">' . $row['user_name'] . "</option>\n";
}

echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score -1):

The first result in Google came up with an example...

http://forums.devarticles.com/mysql-development-50/drop-down-menu-populated-from-a-mysql-database-1811.html

Try to do a little research before posting in the future.